# TikZ \foreach loop with macro-defined list

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, foreach

I have a small problem with the TikZ `\foreach` loop whenever the list, over which we loop, is defined my a macro. The following code example will show my problem:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Picture one:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x/\y in {1.0/2.0, 3.0/4.0} \node[draw] at (\x,\y) {\x--\y};
\end{tikzpicture}

Picture two:

\newcommand{\mymacro}{1.0/2.0, 3.0/4.0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x/\y in {\mymacro} \node[draw] at (\x,\y) {\x--\y};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**The expected result is that both images should look the same.** But in the second image, I only get one node - and both `\x` and `\y` are *each time* expanded to `1.0/2.0, 3.0/4.0`. I hope someone can help.

Comment: Related question: for `child ... foreach` (TikZ documentation section 21.1 "Introduction to the Child Operation) instead, see [tikz pgf - How to expand a macro used in the range of a foreach loop? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67187/how-to-expand-a-macro-used-in-the-range-of-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: Side note if the content to be executed is a "complex command" e.g. `\f{x}` instead of a "single macro" then you must use `expand list` option in [the answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648813/250119), omitting the braces doesn't work; see also these questions [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/648113) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/648102) [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175274)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `\mymacro` isn't expanded by the `\foreach` loop, but only afterwards. You need to remove the braces `{ }` around the macro to make it work:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Picture one:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x/\y in {1.0/2.0, 3.0/4.0} \node[draw] at (\x,\y) {\x--\y};
\end{tikzpicture}

Picture two:

\newcommand{\mymacro}{1.0/2.0, 3.0/4.0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x/\y in \mymacro \node[draw] at (\x,\y) {\x--\y};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that while normally both *arguments* `{\mymacro}` and `\mymacro` are identical, `\foreach` seems to test for `{` and expands the argument if it isn't present.

Comment: @slouwrun: As far as I remember this is an explicit feature of the `\foreach` macro.

Comment: Good! I deleted my shorter answer. Btw. the pgf manual says: *Still in the easiest case, <list> is either a comma-separated list of values surrounded by curly braces or it
is the name of a macro that contain such a list of values.*

Answer (score 4):

Starting with version 3.1.7 (November 2020), *TikZ* supports the `expand list` option for `\foreach`.

From the *TikZ & PGF* manual:

> `/pgf/foreach/expand list={<boolean>}` (default `false`)
> If this key is set to true the contents of the list are fully expanded with `\edef` before further
> processing. This allows using complex macros which generate a list upon expansion without having
> to use an intermediate macro.

So this is particularly useful if the macro that produces the list requires multiple expansions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Picture one:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x/\y in {1.0/2.0, 3.0/4.0} \node[draw] at (\x,\y) {\x--\y};
\end{tikzpicture}

Picture two:

\newcommand{\mymacro}{1.0/2.0, 3.0/4.0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach[expand list] \x/\y in {\mymacro} \node[draw] at (\x,\y) {\x--\y};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```