# Pretty lists for sorting algorithms

Tags: diagrams, arrays

I would like to obtain easily something like in this picture so as to illustrate several sorting algorithms.

[image: sorting]

To produce one line, I would like to use one command of the following kind where the numbers of values is not fixed by advance.

```
\list{\style1}{value1}{\style2}{value2}{\style3}{value3}
```

Here `\style` can define both the background and the border colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a comment/answer to the comments of Peter Grill's [original answer *(+1)*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83732/16595).

The `\List` macro takes one optional argument, the style that should be used if none is specified (i.e. `…,<entry>,…`).

I also took the liberty to use the `node distance` key instead of the hard-coded `(0.5*\i cm,0)` placement.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xstring}
\tikzset{
    raw sort entry/.style={rectangle, thick, draw, node distance=1.5em},
    sort entry black/.style={raw sort entry, black, fill=white},
    sort entry blackgray/.style={raw sort entry, black, fill=gray!25},
    s1/.style={raw sort entry, red, fill=yellow!30},
    s2/.style={raw sort entry, blue, fill=green!20},
    s3/.style={raw sort entry, violet, fill=orange!25}
}
\newcommand*{\List}[2][sort entry black]{%
  \par\noindent%
  \edef\listtoprocess{#2}%
  \def\ListToProcess{}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0]
    \foreach \content in \listtoprocess{
      \IfSubStr{\content}{/}{% true
        \xdef\ListToProcess{\ListToProcess,\content}
      }{%                      false
        \xdef\ListToProcess{\ListToProcess,#1/\content}
      }
    }
    \StrGobbleLeft{\ListToProcess}{1}[\ListToProcess]% removes the first comma (\listToProcess is empty at the start)
    \foreach [count=\i] \Style/\Value in \ListToProcess {
      \ifnum\i=1\relax
        \node [raw sort entry, \Style] (sortnode\i) {\Value};
      \else
        \node [raw sort entry, right of=sortnode\number\numexpr\i-1\relax, \Style] (sortnode\i) {\Value};
      \fi
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\List{s1/1, 2, s3/3}
\List[sort entry blackgray]{s2/1, s1/2, s1/3, 1, s2/2, s3/3, s2/2, s2/3}
\List[s1]{1,2,/3,/2,3}% /3 and /2 falls back to no explicit \Style, so the resulting style is that from the \node [raw sort entry, …]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. Also you should define the parameter into a macro, in case it was a macro in the first place -- My answer was edited and have reverted it.

Comment: @PeterGrill That edit was the reason I noticed the question/answer. I've updated my (your ;)) answer to implement the `\edef`inition of  `#2`.

Comment: Very nice collaboration !

Answer (score 8):

To allow for an arbitrary number of parameters I would recommend a slightly different syntax where you provide a comma separated list in the form:

```
<style>/<value>, <style>/<value>, <style>/<value>, ...
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{style1/.style={thick, draw=red,fill=yellow!30}}
\tikzset{style2/.style={thick, draw=blue,fill=green!20}}
\tikzset{style3/.style={thick, draw=violet,fill=orange!25}}

\newcommand*{\List}[1]{%
\par\noindent%
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=2pt, outer sep=0]
    \edef\ListToProcess{#1}% Allows for parapamater to be defined via a macro.
    \foreach [count=\i] \Style/\Value in \ListToProcess {
        \node [rectangle,\Style] at (0.5*\i cm,0) {\Value};
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\List{style1/1, style2/2, style3/3}
\List{style2/1, style1/2, style1/3, style1/1, style2/2, style3/3, style2/2, style2/3}
\List{style3/1, style2/2, style2/3, style1/2, style1/3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Superb! I was trying to get something similar, but yours is much better :)

Comment: Is there way to use one default value for the style ?

Comment: @projetmbc: Yeah there should be, but I can't seems to get it to work right now.  Be default `\foreach` will use the last value if one is not provided.

Comment: @PeterGrill A not-so-user-friendly way would be to define a default style (e.g. `\tikzset{styledefault/.style={thick, draw=black,fill=white}}`) and provide `styledefault` _before_ `\Style` (i.e. `\node […, styledefault, \Style] …`) and use it as `\List{style1/1, /2, style3/3}`. A more sophisticated solution would be to check `#1` for entries _without_ `/` and prepend `styledefault/` so one can use `\List{style1/1, 2, style3/3}`. [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) will be helpful.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I tried that but ran into difficulties. Was thinking of pre-processing the list to complete it (which is what I think the second part of your comment is about).

Comment: @ErrMist: I revererted code. Need to use a `\edef` in case the parameter is defined in a macro.  Added comment in code -- was looking for the related question but have not been able to find it.

Comment: @PeterGrill Maybe this one: [TikZ \foreach loop with macro-defined list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12091)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: That's similar, but that one does not have the `\edef` solution. I think that solution should be posted there though. You can do it if you want?