# How to write hints in Sudoku cells using the logicpuzzle package?

Tags: sudoku, logicpuzzle

I need to typeset Sudoku tables in LaTeX, and so far I have been able to do most of what I need to do using the `logicpuzzle` package. One of the few missing things is the ability to write hints inside cells, listing all the possible numbers which could go inside that cell.

Looking at the [package documentation](http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/logicpuzzle/logicpuzzle.pdf), I don't see an option to do this using the package alone, so I wonder if I should use a different package altogether, or if there is a way to extend `logicpuzzle` to make it display this instead.

So far, this is what I have:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{logicpuzzle}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\chapter{Sudoku 1}

\begin{logicpuzzle}[rows=9,columns=9,color=orange!50,scale=1.5]
\framepuzzle
\framearea{black}{(1,7)--(4,7)--(4,10)--(1,10)}
\framearea{black}{(4,7)--(7,7)--(7,10)--(4,10)}
\framearea{black}{(7,7)--(10,7)--(10,10)--(7,10)}
\framearea{black}{(1,4)--(4,4)--(4,7)--(1,7)}
\framearea{black}{(4,4)--(7,4)--(7,7)--(7,4)}
\framearea{black}{(7,4)--(10,4)--(10,7)--(10,7)}
\framearea{black}{(1,1)--(1,4)--(4,4)--(4,1)}
\framearea{black}{(4,1)--(7,1)--(7,4)--(4,4)}
\setrow{9}{{},{},{3},{4},{},{5},{6},{},{}}
\setrow{8}{{7},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}}
\setrow{7}{{8},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}}
\setrow{6}{{9},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{7}}
\setrow{5}{{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{8}}
\setrow{4}{{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{9}}
\setrow{3}{{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}}
\setrow{2}{{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}}
\setrow{1}{{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}}
\fillcell{1}{9}
\fillcell{9}{9}
\end{logicpuzzle}

\end{document}
```

This is the resulting Sudoku:

[image]

Is there any way to typeset number hints inside a Sudoku cell using the `logicpuzzle` package?

Ideally, they would look similar to the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94750/sudoku-special-styles-for-hints):

[image]

Comment: Hmm, why don't you use Ti*k*Z for this thing?

Comment: Also, how do you want the hint to look like?

Comment: @JouleV I have no preference as to what the hint would look like at this point, I was mostly curious to see if this was even possible. Ideally, I would break up the cell in 9 parts, and enter the hint in the relevant subcell, so to say

Comment: @JouleV I suppose I could use TikZ, but I found this package which looked perfect for what I need to do. Well, except for the hints :P

Comment: It is _always_ possible (but I don't know if it is possible with your package). Please show how the hints should look like.

Comment: @JouleV Gotcha! I have updated my question with a screenshot and a link to another question on this site. I don't need any highlights in the hint, or anything special, just the numbers with that format would already be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I define some simple macros for that.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newcommand\inserthint[3]{%
    \foreach \i in {#3} {
        \ifnum\i<4
            \draw ({(#1-0.5)+(\i*0.25)},#2+0.25) node[font=\scriptsize] {\i};
        \else
            \ifnum\i>6
                \draw ({(#1-2)+(\i*0.25)},#2-0.25) node[font=\scriptsize] {\i};
            \else
                \draw ({(#1-1.25)+(\i*0.25)},#2) node[font=\scriptsize] {\i};
            \fi
        \fi
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick,step=3] (0,0) grid (9,9);
\draw (0,0) grid (9,9);
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={minimum size=1cm},xshift=-.5cm,yshift=-.5cm]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\node at (1,6) {9};
\node at (1,7) {8};
\node at (1,8) {7};
\node at (3,9) {3};
\node at (4,9) {4};
\node at (6,9) {5};
\node at (7,9) {6};
\node at (9,6) {7};
\node at (9,5) {8};
\node at (9,4) {9};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-.5cm,yshift=-.5cm]
\inserthint{1}{9}{1,...,9}
\inserthint{4}{6}{2,5,6,3,7}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In case you need to fill, we should rearrange the code a bit. As for the "normal" nodes, you only have to add option `fill=...`. As for the "hint" nodes, I added an argument to the macro.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newcommand\inserthint[4]{%
    \fill[#4] (#1-.5,#2-.5) rectangle (#1+.5,#2+.5);
    \foreach \i in {#3} {
        \ifnum\i<4
            \draw ({(#1-0.5)+(\i*0.25)},#2+0.25) node[font=\scriptsize] {\i};
        \else
            \ifnum\i>6
                \draw ({(#1-2)+(\i*0.25)},#2-0.25) node[font=\scriptsize] {\i};
            \else
                \draw ({(#1-1.25)+(\i*0.25)},#2) node[font=\scriptsize] {\i};
            \fi
        \fi
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={minimum size=1cm},xshift=-.5cm,yshift=-.5cm]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\node at (1,6) {9};
\node at (1,7) {8};
\node at (1,8) {7};
\node at (3,9) {3};
\node at (4,9) {4};
\node at (6,9) {5};
\node at (7,9) {6};
\node at (9,6) {7};
\node at (9,5) {8};
\node[fill=blue!30] at (9,4) {9};
\node[fill=red!30] at (2,3) {};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-.5cm,yshift=-.5cm]
\inserthint{1}{9}{1,...,9}{yellow}
\inserthint{4}{6}{2,5,6,3,7}{green!50}
\end{scope}
\draw[very thick,step=3] (0,0) grid (9,9);
\draw (0,0) grid (9,9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]