# radix sort tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, algorithms, arrays

I want to visualize Radix sort to look like [image: this] but I can't find a way based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141065/what-are-the-easiest-cleanest-way-to-create-arrays-for-illustrating-quicksort-wi)

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: To add to what @HenriMenke said, this is nearly a good question: some Tikz code showing how you tried to tackle your problem with an explanation of what went wrong would make it a really good question.  The question is likely to be put on hold as too broad, but if you edit the question, it is possible to reopen it.