# TikZ: \foreach in macro with argument as list

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, foreach

The code below generates:

[image]

What I expect is:

[image]

Why does the \foreach seem to treat the entire list as one value?
How do I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\separate}{m}
{
  \StrLeft{#1}{1}[\head]
  \StrBehind[1]{#1}{\head}[\tail]
  \IfInteger{\tail}{\head,\separate{\tail}}{\head}
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\map}{m}
{
  \def\list{#1}
  \foreach \i in \list
  {
    [\i]
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\arg{3669887}

\arg

\separate{\arg}

\map{\separate{\arg}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The argument to `\map` is `\separate{\arg}`, so what you get is `\foreach \i in \separate{\arg}` which is not what you want.

Comment: Related: [`\foreach` loop with macro-defined list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12091/5764)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already use *xstring* to poke around in the string, so you could also do it like this:

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\arg{3669887}

\StrLen{\arg}[\strlen]

\foreach \x in {1,...,\strlen}
{[\StrChar{\arg}{\x}]%
}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 7):

With your code you're essentially doing the same as

```
\foreach \i in {\separate{\arg}}{[\i]}
```

so there is only one cycle to do.

You have to first separate the string and then call `\foreach`, which can't do that job.

---

Here's how I would do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\separate}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF #1
   {
    \linus_separate:o { #2 }
   }
   {
    \linus_separate:n { #2 }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\map}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF #1
   {
    \linus_map:o { #2 }
   }
   {
    \linus_map:n { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \linus_separate:n #1
 {
  % split the input into parts "at nothing"
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_linus_list_seq { } { #1 }
  % deliver the input separated by commas
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l_linus_list_seq { ,~ } { ,~ } { ,~ }
 }
% a variant for a macro input
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \linus_separate:n { o }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \linus_map:n #1
 {
  % split the input into parts "at nothing"
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_linus_list_seq { } { #1 }
  % deliver the input by enclosing the parts in brackets
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_linus_list_seq { [##1] }
 }
% a variant for a macro input
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \linus_map:n { o }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\def\arg{3669887}

\arg

\separate*{\arg}

\map*{\arg}

\separate{1234}

\map{1234}

\end{document}
```

However you probably don't need the `\separate` function any more. I'd keep distinct the macros when the input is "symbolic", such as `\arg`, from when it is "explicit"; thus the two calls `\map*` and `\map`.

[image]