# csuse with foreach

Tags: foreach, etoolbox, comma-separated-list

Am having difficulty determining the correct syntax for using 
`\csuse` from
[the `etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)
with a `\foreach`.

I have a list, and for *each* element in this list I need to create a new list.  To simplify the MWE, I used `\IfStrEq` to define the new list using `\csgdef`.

The problem in in the second `\foreach` where I have an additional curly brace:

```
{\csuse{ContentFor\x}}
```

which should *not* be needed as per [TikZ \foreach loop with macro-defined list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12091/tikz-foreach-loop-with-macro-defined-list).

---

If I leave out the `{}` in the second `\foreach` I get:

> Argument of \csuse has an extra }

With the `{}` it compiles and I get:

[image]

However, the desired output is:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand*{\MyList}{ABC,XYZ}%

\begin{document}

%% For each element of \MyList I need to create a new list.
\foreach \x in \MyList {%
    % In my actual use case the list that gets defined for each element of \MyList
    % is based on timestamps of files, but as that is not relevant to this 
    % particular issue I left out that complexity, to make this test case easier to read.
    \IfStrEq{\x}{ABC}{%
        \csgdef{ContentFor\x}{FileA,FileB,FileC}%
    }{%
        \csgdef{ContentFor\x}{FileX,FileY,FileZ}%
    }%
}%

% Now, only after I have ALL the lists created, I want to print EACH list
% for each element of \MyList.
\foreach \x in \MyList {%
    \par\x=
    \foreach \y in {\csuse{ContentFor\x}} {% <--- The {} around \csuse{} should NOT be necessary.
        \par\hspace*{1.0cm}\y
    }%
}%

%%% This is the expected output:
%   \par ABC=
%   \foreach \y in {FileA,FileB,FileC} {%
%       \par\hspace*{1.0cm}\y
%   }%
%   \par XYZ=
%   \foreach \y in {FileX,FileY,FileZ} {%
%       \par\hspace*{1.0cm}\y
%   }%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the usual expansion issue. If `\foreach` finds a brace, it doesn't do expansion and expects a list, which in this case is just one element, that is `\csuse{ContentFor\x}`. Otherwise, it expands *once* the token that follows and the expansion should be a list, putting it in braces. However, the first level expansion of `\csuse{ContentFor\x}` is

```
\ifcsname ContentFor\x\endcsname\csname\ContentFor\x\expandafter\endcsname\fi
```

which is definitely not a list.

You have to fully expand the `\csuse`. Depending on what's expected to be in the list, you need one of the following two methods.

### First method

The usual full expansion method

```
\foreach \x in \MyList {%
\par\x=
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\foreach\noexpand\y in {\csuse{ContentFor\x}}}\x {%
    \par\hspace*{1.0cm}\y
    }%
}
```

will do if the list is fully expandable, that is, it contains only ASCII characters. If the list may contain “dangerous” items, such as `\textbf`.

### Second method

If the list contains “dangerous” items, you have to limit its expandability:

```
\foreach \x in \MyList {%
    % In my actual use case the list that gets defined for each element of \MyList
    % is based on timestamps of files, but as that is not relevant to this 
    % particular issue I left out that complexity, to make this test case easier to read.
    \IfStrEq{\x}{ABC}{%
        \protected\csgdef{ContentFor\x}{FileA,FileB,FileC}%
    }{%
        \protected\csgdef{ContentFor\x}{FileX,FileY,FileZ}%
    }%
}

\foreach \x in \MyList {%
\par\x=
\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\foreach\noexpand\y in {\csuse{ContentFor\x}}}\x {%
    \par\hspace*{1.0cm}\y
    }%
}
```

Note that `\csuse` requires *two* steps of expansion to arrive at, say, `\ContentForABC`.

---

Just for fun, an implementation with `xparse` and `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\createlist}{ m m }
 {
  \clist_new:c { g_grill_list_#1_clist }
  \clist_gset:cn { g_grill_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\createcontents}{ m m }
 {
  \clist_new:c { g_grill_list_content_#1_clist }
  \clist_set:cn { g_grill_list_content_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\processlist}{ m +m }
 {
  \clist_map_inline:cn { g_grill_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\processcontents}{ m +m }
 {
  \clist_map_inline:cn { g_grill_list_content_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\createlist{MyList}{ABC,XYZ}
\createcontents{ABC}{FileA, FileB, FileC}
\createcontents{XYZ}{FileX, FileY, FileZ}

\begin{document}

\processlist{MyList}{%
  \par#1=
  \processcontents{#1}{\par\hspace*{1cm}##1}%
}
\end{document}
```

In the second argument to `\processlist` and `\processcontents` you can refer to the current item (`\x` and `\y` in your `\foreach` statements) as `#1`; in the inner `\processcontents` you have to double the `#`.

[image]

Comment: Based on your earlier comment I found that `\edef\ContentForThisX{\csuse{ContentFor\x}}` followed by `\foreach \y in \ContentForThisX ` works just fine.  Is there an inherent problem in this for the case of no "dangerous" content?

Comment: @PeterGrill No, it's just the same as the first method, just slightly less efficient.

Comment: Correction ■ the 2-level expansion of \csuse is `\ContentForABC\fi`, not `\ContentForABC`. ■ (it's not recommended to rely on "undocumented behavior" (i.e. the macro requires exactly 2 expansion step) anyway. Could use csname or expl3's `:c` argument type) ■ (see the comment above for the edef, it's much cleaner, although I don't know if it's really less efficient or not -- I suspect not) ■ The problem is not just that the single expansion does not give the desired result, but that the initial content is **not a single token**. For example `\def\f #1{#1,2}\foreach \x in \f{1}{\x}
` won't work

Answer (score 0):

This is the "modern" solution using TikZ `expand list` -- just in case someone come across this question in the future:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand*{\MyList}{ABC,XYZ}%

\begin{document}

%% For each element of \MyList I need to create a new list.
\foreach \x in \MyList {%
    % In my actual use case the list that gets defined for each element of \MyList
    % is based on timestamps of files, but as that is not relevant to this 
    % particular issue I left out that complexity, to make this test case easier to read.
    \IfStrEq{\x}{ABC}{%
        \csgdef{ContentFor\x}{FileA,FileB,FileC}%
    }{%
        \csgdef{ContentFor\x}{FileX,FileY,FileZ}%
    }%
}%

% Now, only after I have ALL the lists created, I want to print EACH list
% for each element of \MyList.
\foreach \x in \MyList {%
    \par\x=
    \foreach[expand list] \y in {\csuse{ContentFor\x}} {
        \par\hspace*{1.0cm}\y
    }%
}%

\end{document}
```

Credit to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648813/250119).