# Predefined lists to loop through by \@for or \foreach

Tags: lists

since I needed a loop command to implement a ton of graphics more easily, I searched the web for options. I soon found \foreach from the tikz package to do what I want. But even though this worked, I soon needed to change the code to make a predefined list. So I did the following:

```
\newcommand*{\BOTH}{EE, EMu , MuMu}
\foreach \p in \BOTH{
   \p
}
```

What it does though is taking \BOTH as one text object and not as a list to loop through. Adding extra brackets does not help.
When I searched for other options, I found the \@for command but that is somehow unknown to my LaTeX compiler. So is there any way to just create a list into a variable?
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: \@for can only be used in a context where `@` is a letter so in a package file or after `\makeatletter`

Comment: Related: [TikZ `\foreach` loop with macro-defined list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12091/5764)

Comment: Related: [How to iterate over a comma separated list?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159118/5764)