# Problem with catchfile package

Tags: external-files, tikz-external, import

I want to use the `catchfile` package to import the data of nodes from external file `ver.dat` as following:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\CatchFileDef{\myver}{ver.dat}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach [count=\i] \coord in {\myver}{
     \node (p\i) at \coord {\i};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

where the file `ver.dat` is `(1,0),(0,1)`.

But the above code doesn't work, what's wrong?

Comment: The main problem here is that `\myver` is not expanded; you can see this by inserting `\show\coord` inside the `\foreach` loop to see what `\coord` looks like. You need to remove the braces around `\myver` so it's properly expanded, as suggested in [TikZ `\foreach` loop with macro-defined list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12091/5764).

Comment: @Werner Thanks! Can you write it down as an answer?

Comment: Essentially it's a duplicate.

Comment: I worked out that the problem was lack of expansion however even with the hint from @Werner I am able to get the MWE to work, so I'd like to see a full solution. My understanding is that Werner is saying that the `\foreach` line should be: `\foreach [count=\i] \coord in \myver {...}` but when I do this `\coord` is still `{(1,0), (0,1)}`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Andrew: That's exactly right. Are you sure `ver.dat` contains *only* `(1,0), (0,1)` (without the braces `{`...`}`)?

Comment: @Werner Thanks, you are right: I must have changed it when I was playing with the question. Cheers.