# How to use macro as a `foreach` range?

Tags: expansion, foreach, comma-separated-list

These two loops do not produce the same result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {a,b,c} {%
    \i+
}

\def\Index{a,b,c}
\foreach \i in {\Index} {%
    \i+
}

\end{document}
```

[image: two different lines]

Why is this? How do I get `\foreach` to iterate over the comma-separated content of `\Index` even though it looks like a single token?

Comment: Look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12091/1952 and replace `\foreach \i in {\Index}` by `\foreach \i in \Index`

Comment: @Ignasi Wops, cheers. I've marked the post as duplicate.