# How define a command with argument to specify which list to return?

Tags: lists, foreach, ifthenelse

I want to define a command that returns one or another list, as a list enclosed in braces, that, in my real document and not this MWE, I can use as an argument to something else (namely, the list over which to iterate in a TikZ `\foreach` structure).

The following does *not* work!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\whichlist}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{#1=1}{{1,2,3}}%
     {{4,5}}
}

\begin{document}

I want to get \verb!{1,2,3}! but I get:
\whichlist{1}

I want to get \verb!{4,5}! but I get:
\whichlist{2}

Fanciful usage for MWE purposes is:

\begin{tikzpicture}    
  %\foreach \x in {\whichlist{1}} { \draw (0,0)--(\x,\x); }; % this gives error
  % Preceding, uncommented, should give same result as this:
  \foreach \x in {1,2,3}{ \draw (0,0)--(\x,\x*\x);}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Braces don't print as braces: they are special characters. You *do* get `{1,2,3}`, but the braces print nothing. Please, be more specific about the intended application, because this will definitely not work in a `\foreach` context.

Comment: @egreg: I added sample usage. Hope that helps to indicate my aim.

Comment: By the way, part of this is case 2 of my answer in [verbatim - Why can't I use <some macro> inside the argument of <some other macro>? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645995/why-cant-i-use-some-macro-inside-the-argument-of-some-other-macro), read if you're interested -- Also [TikZ \foreach loop with macro-defined list - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12091/tikz-foreach-loop-with-macro-defined-list)

Answer (score 2):

You *do* get `{1,2,3}`, but the braces are group delimiters, so print nothing. And no, your attempt ***cannot*** work, because `\whichlist{1}` is not the list, but the instructions to *print* it.

You can use `\foreach \x in \foo {...}` provided `\foo` is a macro that expands to a list after a single expansion step: so if you do

```
\newcommand{\foo}{1,2,3}
```

then

```
\foreach \x in \foo {...}
```

would work the same as

```
\foreach \x in {1,2,3}{...}
```

Your `\whichlist{1}` does not yield a list after one expansion step.

You might do as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\preparelists}{O{default}m}
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_murray_lists_#1_seq }
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:cn { l_murray_lists_#1_seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\fetchlist}{O{default}m}
 {
  { \seq_item:cn { l_murray_lists_#1_seq } { #2 } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\preparelists{
  {1,2,3}
  {a,b,c,d}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}    
  \expanded{\unexpanded{\foreach \x in }\fetchlist{1}} {
     \draw (0,0)--(\x,\x*\x/2);
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but of course that thing is quite inconvenient. Here's a less heavy method, but note the braces around `\fetchlist{1}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\preparelists}{O{default}m}
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_murray_lists_#1_seq }
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:cn { l_murray_lists_#1_seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\fetchlist}{O{default}m}
 {
  { \seq_item:cn { l_murray_lists_#1_seq } { #2 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \expandedforeach #1 in #2
 {
  \use:e { \exp_not:n { \foreach #1~in~ } #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\preparelists{
  {1,2,3}
  {a,b,c,d}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}    
  \expandedforeach \x in {\fetchlist{1}} {
     \draw (0,0)--(\x,\x*\x/2);
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can define as many lists of lists as you wish, just give them names: for instance if you want to name `foo` this list of lists you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\preparelists}{O{default}m}
 {
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_murray_lists_#1_seq }
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:cn { l_murray_lists_#1_seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\fetchlist}{O{default}m}
 {
  { \seq_item:cn { l_murray_lists_#1_seq } { #2 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \expandedforeach #1 in #2
 {
  \use:e { \exp_not:n { \foreach #1~in~ } #2 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\preparelists[foo]{
  {1,2,3}
  {a,b,c,d}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}    
  \expandedforeach \x in {\fetchlist[foo]{1}} {
     \draw (0,0)--(\x,\x*\x/2);
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The default name is `default`.

Comment: No way to do it without `\ExplSyntaxOn` and exp3?

Comment: @murray Of course there is a way (**everything** are built as macros on plain TeX (and possibly some engine extensions), after all), but some programmers nowadays prefer expl3.

Comment: @egreg: OK. Your code works, to my delight. I was surprised that no separators were required between the lists in the `\preparelist` expression. The ability to use the optional parameter to `\preparelists` was especially helpful: in the actual application, I'm using two sets of lists -- one for x-axis tick labels and another for y-axis tick labels.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `\foreach` from TikZ has something impractical syntax of its parameters, so you must use `\expanded` in order to get the list as a result of a macro. You can define `\myforeach` macro as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\listlist#1{\ifcase#1 \or
   {1,2,3}\or   % 1
   {4,5}\or     % 2
   {6,7,8}\fi   % 3
}
\def\myforeach#1inlist#2{\expanded{\noexpand\foreach\noexpand#1 in \listlist{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \myforeach \x inlist 1 {
     \draw (0,0)--(\x,\x*\x/2);
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Of course, you need not any `\ExplSyntaxOn`, only TeX primitives are used here.